# How to send data from Raspberry Pi Python Script to Android App

Tags: android-studio, raspberry-pi

My senior project partner and I are trying to send data from a Raspberry Pi 4B to an Android Smartphone that is using Android Studio to make an app. The goal is to send multiple data readings from different sensors that are read in the python script in Raspberry Pi to an Android Smartphone. We have been having immense trouble with this and have looked off of many different posts to have nothing work. We have little to no experience with python and android studio. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you connecting the raspberry pi and the smartphone? wifi? usb-cable? or something else?

Comment: We were originally trying to use Bluetooth, but we quickly realized we had no idea what we were doing. Where the Pi is being used it has no access to WIFI, so we were trying to steer clear of a WIFI based communication. We are open to suggestions on which medium to use. What would you do if you were in our same position?

Comment: is there a physical limitation between the phone and the raspberry pi, i mean can they be connected with a usb cable or is there a distance factor involved?

Comment: They can be connected using USB. We originally wanted the project to be "wireless" meaning that the Raspberry Pi and Android Phone would not be connected and would use Bluetooth to communicate.That being said, we ran into a road block and couldn't get the Bluetooth to work, so if USB is the easiest solution then we have no problem using it. The only limitation is that we are unfamiliar with how to transfer data even with USB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to provide one possible solution. Since you are already using python in the raspberry pi to collect data from sensors, you could extend the script to relay that data to a HTTP REST api endpoint within the pi, using some HTTP microservice libraries like flask, bottle, etc. After this you need to open the communication between the raspberry pi and your phone which are connected via a USB cable. The simplest way of doing so would be to forward the port of your microservice using `adb`, like so

```sh
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

The above command needs to be run on the raspberry pi (after you setup up adb in it). The above command forwards the raspberry pi port 8080 to the  android phones port 8080. Now the only thing you need to do is setup your app to periodically send HTTP requests to the local port 8080 and retrieve the information from raspberry pi. I do not have much experience with Android development so you have to research further on the viability of the app communicating with the forwarded port (permissions and security procedures to be bypassed), but this would be one of the simplest ways to setup communication involving an android device.

Comment: I will try this tonight and see what I can come up with. I really appreciate your help!